# $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x$ is a local minimiser, show that $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion

I am able to prove that $x$ must be a stationary point, i.e., $\nabla f(x) = 0$. However I feel the proof given in my lecture is wrong, the key part of the proof uses the Taylor series expansion
$$f(x) \leq f(x + td) = f(x) + \frac{t^2}{2}d^T\nabla^2f(x)d + o(t^2),$$
where $d$ can be arbitraty direction vector.

The problem is the above expansion only works when all **third** order and below partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous, not just twice, according to Taylor's theorem. I believe the result is still correct, but how to prove it rigorously?

Update: turns out for the Taylor series expansion in the above form, $f$ only needs to be in $C^2$, hence the proof is actually correct.

Comment: I think you don’t need $C^3$. $C^2$ is good enough to state Taylor’s theorem.

Comment: I believe for this Taylor expansion to be true, you only need $f$ to be twice differentiable.  In fact that's the definition of the second derivative.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your comments. It seems that there are different versions of Taylor's theorem with different types of remainder forms. For the above form, twice differentiable is enough.

Comment: To be complete, what is being used here is a first order Taylor expansion with second order remainder. This term has the form $1/2z^TH(z)z$ for some $z$. One can show that in some sense positive definite matrices are an open set, i.e the positive definite property is stable under small perturbations, so if $H(a)$ is positive definite, then so is $H(z)$ if z is close enough to a.

Comment: So you are right, the argument your professor gave is not correct (unless this is another form of Taylor’s I’m not aware of). But the statement of the theorem still holds.

Comment: I think I am wrong. The form given by my professor only requires $f$ to be twice differentiable, which is implied by $f \in C^2$, and this result was unknown to me so it caused the confusion. What needs to be prove here is a necessary condition, I am aware of what you mentioned, which can be used to prove the other direction: if $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is positive definitive and $x$ is a stationary point, then $x$ is a strictly local minimiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments, here is a proof for my own question.

For a twice continuously differentiable function $f$, *if we use Peano form of the remainder*, its Taylor series expansion can be written as
$$f(x + td) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^Tdt + \frac{t^2}{2}d^T\nabla^2f(x)d + o(t^2)$$
for any $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $|t|$ small enough (how small it needs to be depends on $d$). My confusion originated from I used other forms of the remainder, which requires more conditions.

If $x$ is a local minimiser, then we know $\nabla f(x) = 0$ and
$$f(x + td) - f(x) = \frac{t^2}{2}d^T\nabla^2f(x)d + o(t^2) \geq 0.$$
Divide both sides by $t^2$ and let $t \rightarrow 0^+$, we have
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x + td) - f(x)}{t^2} = \frac{1}{2}d^T\nabla^2f(x)d \geq 0$$
for all $d$ and hence $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive semi-definite.